# What happened to getContainerRequestFilters in jersey2?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use `new ResourceConfig().getContainerRequestFilters().add()` in my application but this method is no longer available.Is there an alternative to this or is this entirely dropped?

Comment: Just use `register`. Or if you are package scanning `rc.packages(...)`, if you have the filter annotated with `@Provider`, it will get automatically picked up

Comment: See [the API](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html)